# Secure Alternatives to next-auth with 'require-auth' Component in Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

I'm developing a project in Next.js 13 and considering using a `require auth` component to protect routes that require authentication. The implementation of the component is as follows:

```
import { AuthContext } from '@/app/contexts/auth-context';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';

const RequireAuth = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const { isAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isAuth) {
            router.push('/');
        }
    }, [isAuth]);

    return children;
};

export default RequireAuth;
```

### Related links:

- [Built project on vercel](https://tests-mongo-ts-829f-cb9mw2g85-collaxd.vercel.app/)
- [GitHub repository](https://github.com/collaxd/tests-mongo---ts)

I would like to know if this approach is safe and appropriate for ensuring route protection in my Next.js 13 project regarding user authentication. As I am new to programming, I'm seeking community guidance to understand if this component is a secure and recommended practice.

Additional questions:

- Is there a more secure or recommended way to implement route authentication in Next.js 13?
  What are the best practices to ensure the security of user authentication in my project?

Bonus question:

- In addition to route authentication, I'm planning to use MongoDB in the backend for authentication in the future. Considering this, are there any additional security considerations I should take into account?

I appreciate any help, clarification, or suggestions for alternatives to ensure the security of authentication and API protection in my project!